# VIM Sendscreen and behind the scenes buffer

Tags: vim

I'm currently using vim via cygwin in conjunction with screen and screen-vim. Screen-vim has SendScreen which takes the entire current buffer and sends it to the attached screen. While this is nice, for my application I really need a line by line solution. Currently I'm using the following mapping:

```
map <leader>d "kyy<cr>:tabe<cr>"kp<ESC>:ScreenSend<cr>:q<cr>
```

This does the job but feels kind of wonky. Is there a better solution? I'm specifically looking for something that either opens a buffer so that the user doesn't notice or implements the same functionality in a neater manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the README:](https://github.com/ervandew/screen#usage)

> Once you have the shell open, you can then send **visual selections** to it using the command :ScreenSend.

And [from `:help screen`:](https://github.com/ervandew/screen/blob/master/doc/screen.txt#L145)

> :ScreenSend
>
> Send the visual selection **or** the entire buffer contents to the running gnu screen shell window.

So…

```
V:ScreenSend<CR>
```

or

```
:.ScreenSend<CR>
```

Comment: Guess I was too tired and overlooked this; thanks!